# Property list in a Model property couldn't be mapped while trying to migrate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting up a migration in an MVC5 that has a Model that's called "Order" with 3 properties, one of them is a class of PizzaModel. PizzaModel has the code below, what I'm trying to do is to enable multiple instances of pizzas in a single Order, so one Order can have many pizzas.

```
public class PizzaModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<PizzaSet> Pizzas { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }


}
public class PizzaSet
{
    public enum Toppings { GreenOlives, BulgarianCheese, Onions, Mushrooms, Peppers, Basil, Sausage, Pepperoni, Ham, Beef }
    public enum Sauces { BBQ, Islands }
    public enum Size { Personal, Medium, Family }

    public Size PizzaSize { get; set; }
    public List<Sauces> PizzaSauces { get; set; }
    public List<Toppings> PizzaToppings { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a wrong approach for a migration?

Comment: Which ORM are you using? Entity Framework 6, EF Core, something else?

Comment: I am using the EF Core ORM

Comment: And, what is the error?

Comment: "The property 'PizzaSet.PizzaSauces" could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<Sauces' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type." For clarification, I tried using a List<string>. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `enums` as your list type.

If youre storing this data in a database. The database needs a placeholder to store the enum values.

In general this is done by a table.

So, if you make classes of your enums, these will be translated to tables and the mapping will work.

```
public class Topping 
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Use this class as your list type.

Do note that you need to fill the `topping`, `sauces` and etc. tables. The good news is: you can extend them without changing the code :-)

---

Alternatively,  you can put the

```
[NotMapped]
```

attribute on your property.  Do note that this won't help you in your specific case because it would not store the toppings in the database then.

Answer (score 2):

Your `PizzaSet` class is using a List of Enums, which will not map to a database schema in EF.

If you want to use an enum for `Sauces` and `Toppings` and want to allow multiple selections, you need to use the `[Flags]` property for the enum, to treat it as a bit field.

```
public class PizzaSet
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Toppings { GreenOlives = 1, BulgarianCheese = 2, Onions = 4, Mushrooms = 8, Peppers = 16, Basil = 32, Sausage = 64, Pepperoni = 128, Ham = 256, Beef = 512 }

    [Flags]
    public enum Sauces { BBQ = 1, Islands = 2 }

    public enum Size { Personal, Medium, Family }

    public Size PizzaSize { get; set; }
    public Sauces PizzaSauces { get; set; }
    public Toppings PizzaToppings { get; set; }
}
```

Then `Toppings` and `Sauces` become a bit field of possible values (notice the values will need to represent unique bits)

To select multiple toppings:-

```
PizzaSet ps = new PizzaSet();

ps.Toppings = Toppings.GreenOlives | Toppings.Peppers;
```

However, given your list of toppings and sauces may change over time, it's probably better to have a separate table that lists toppings, and use a join table (since it's EF Core)

Comment: Yup, I am creating a separate table for the toppings and sauces, appreciate it.

Comment: Nevertheless: nice option!